# Swift add constraints to UIScrollView subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm new to using subviews but for some reason add constraints to `scrollView` do not show the subview. It only work when using `.frame`. Please take a look at my code and let me know.
Thank you.

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let myView = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    scrollView.addSubview(myView)
    myView.backgroundColor = .brown
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: If you change the `UIImageView` to a plain `UIView`, does it show up?

Comment: all views behave the same. the way around it is to have top anchor inside the scrollView and have and have left, right anchor to `view` this is weird that it behave this way or why it should but again apple been pushing too many buggy apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because of the way `UIScrollView` is sized in relationship to its parent and children when using autolayout.

The first set of constraints (between the scrollview and its parent) you have ensures that the frame of the scrollview is pinned to the edges of the root view.

The second set of constraints (between the scrollview and its child) is just ensuring that the content size of the scrollview is equal to the size of the subview. In essence, this constraint ends up modifying the content size of the scroll view, not the frame of the subview. The subview is blank and has no content so its size is 0. This makes the content size of the scrollview 0.

```
print(scrollView.frame)
(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
print(scrollView.bounds)
(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 736.0)
print(scrollView.contentSize)
(0.0, 0.0)
print(myView.frame)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

This behavior is explained a bit in this [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

If what you really want is for the child view to fill the entire frame of the scrollview, you can do that explicitly:

```
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```